# Property methods in not-called class

Tags: python, class, memory, properties, attributes

```
class Parrot:
    def __init__(self):
        self._voltage = 100000

    @property
    def voltage(self):
        """Get the current voltage."""
        return self._voltage
```

I have the code above (found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr)) and I wish to understand if there is any usability for not calling the class and getting the following result.

```
>>> Parrot.voltage
<property at 0x7f19e83cdf48>
```

I understand that the usual would be

```
>>> Parrot().voltage
100000
```

For usability, I mean that `Parrot.voltage` has many methods of the @property available, such as `deleter, fdel, getter`, etc. However, I am not understanding how to use these.

Comment: what is the problem in creating the object. Without object class is not initilised hence can't get those values

Comment: What do you mean *"any usability"*? That's just an artefact of the way properties are implemented, as a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) on the class rather than an attribute on the instance.

Comment: `p = Parrot` just makes `p` a reference to `Parrot` and so `x = p()` would be equivalent to `x = Parrot()`.

Answer (score 0):

> I wish to understand if there is any usability for not calling the class and getting the following result.

```
>>> Parrot.voltage
<property at 0x7f19e83cdf48>
```

Well, you could ask the same question about getting a function back when looking up a method on a class, ie:

```
bruno@bigb:~$ python3
>>> class Foo():
...     def bar(self):
...         return 42
... 
>>> Foo.bar
<function Foo.bar at 0x7fab209c5510>
```

In this example, you could keep a reference to this function and call it later passing it a `Foo` instance as `self` argument:

```
>>> f = Foo.bar
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> f(foo)
42
>>>
```

It's actually just what Python does when you call the method on an instance (using `foo.bar()` instead of `Foo.bar(foo)`). You could do the same with your `property` object:

```
>>> class Parrot:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self._voltage = 100000
...     @property
...     def voltage(self):
...         """Get the current voltage."""
...         return self._voltage
... 
>>> p = Parrot()
>>> Parrot.voltage.__get__(p)
100000
>>>
```

Here again, that's actually what Python does behind the scene when it sees something like:

```
>>> p.voltage
```

FWIW, python's functions are descriptors too so the real equivalent of `foo.bar()` is actually `Foo.bar.__get__(foo)()`

All this might look useless, and you usually don't use methods nor properties that way indeed - you just look them up on the instances, not on the class, and let Python do the grunt work. But having the whole object model implemented in terms of a couple simple concepts (classes, metaclasses, callables and the attribute resolution rules - including the descriptor protocol) makes the language highly dynamic and gives  opportunities to hook into the whole mechanism and customize it. As an example (general example I mean) this is specially handy for framework code by vastly reducing the boilerplate.